# Why is it "says" not "said"?

Tags: present-tense

The job of a student leader is onerous,  he **says**, and you can become overwhelmed by the responsibilities and workload. “So you must set up an action framework, and follow it through,” he **advises**.

Above is an article, the interviewee was interviewed by someone, which was in the past. Then why is present tense used?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be that the article wants to remain current, and therefore uses the present tense.  The interviewer wouldn't want a reader to think the information has gone stale, and therefore doesn't use the past tense.

Until the interviewee changes his mind, present tense is okay to use as the interviewee still has the same opinion.